# How to fix shaking geometry on models with large shared coordinates

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, revit, autodesk-bim360

I'm loading multiple Revit models in the Forge modelviewer. To align them properly I am using the following load options as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051256/forge-viewer-loading-multiple-revit-models-with-shared-coordinates/57052556#57052556)

```
var modelOptions = {
    sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath(),
    globalOffset: { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 },
    applyRefPoint: true,
    isAEC: true
};
```

This works fine on Revit files where the project base point doesn't have too large coordinates. However, if the project base point of a Revit file has large coordinates ( like x:6698000, y:297500) then this results in shaking behavior when rotating the model or even a messed up triangulated view.

This problem also seems to happen when you set the placementTransform to a large coordinate as can be seen in the sample [here](https://jsbin.com/bejewumaye/1/edit?html,js,output)

How can I solve this shaking behavior on these kind of models?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adjusting the offset using globaloffset...

Here's an example:

[Model aggregating in viewer - coordinate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764754/model-aggregating-in-viewer-coordinate-issue/53858720#53858720)

Comment: Adusting the offset indeed solves the shaking problem, but how do I determine the offset before the model is loaded. Can I determine it somehow from the loaded document?

Comment: Not easily.  It would require side loading and decoding the properties database first, to get the global origin, before loading the model with the offset applied.  If you have the option of saving it to a database or local-storage, then you could apply it on subsequent loads.